# usage of "col" parameter Plot function in R

Tags: r

I saw an example of plot function in R, in which the "col" parameter had a value which was a variable rather than a colour value (eg. "blue","red" etc). For example in the example below, the col parameter points to variable "Region", and the graph shows Year in X axis and Sales in Y axis, with the points colored for Region (third dimension). I checked the documentation for plot function and also the color parameter, but there was no indication that the col parameter can take a variable name rather than colour values. I would like to understand whether I am looking at the right documentation.

```
year = c(1990:1994)

sales = c(1:5)

region = c('East','East','West','North','South')

SalesData = data.frame(sales,year,region)   

with(SalesData,plot(year,sales,col=region))
```

Comment: See `?par` and the section `Color Specification`.

Comment: @nicola you can copy an excerpt from the docs and post it as an answer.

Comment: @nicola the color specification doesn't give any such information. Please read my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the most used function to generate plots in R is `plot`, you'll find the most useful information under the `?par` documentation. In it, there is a `Color Specification` section that describes how you can set colors to your plot. Here an excerpt:

```
 Colors can be specified in several different ways. The simplest
 way is with a character string giving the color name (e.g.,
 ‘"red"’).  A list of the possible colors can be obtained with the
 function ‘colors’.  Alternatively, colors can be specified
 directly in terms of their RGB components with a string of the
 form ‘"#RRGGBB"’ where each of the pairs ‘RR’, ‘GG’, ‘BB’ consist
 of two hexadecimal digits giving a value in the range ‘00’ to
 ‘FF’.  Colors can also be specified by giving an index into a
 small table of colors, the ‘palette’: indices wrap round so with
 the default palette of size 8, ‘10’ is the same as ‘2’.  This
 provides compatibility with S.  Index ‘0’ corresponds to the
 background color.  Note that the palette (apart from ‘0’ which is
 per-device) is a per-session setting.
```

Note that in your case you are not passing a `character` to the `col` argument, but a `factor` that is basically an integer value. Furthermore, you can specify as many colors as the points you have to plot, so you can declare the color of each point.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have read this text in the documentation before posting this question. This text from the document only tells you about using color values such as red or hex code etc. but where does it mention that a factor could be passed as you have mentioned in your comment text?. How would a learner like me know from reading the document that col could take a factor value that could be a field/variable from the data set?

Comment: I guess that what you mention are general R concepts. First: a factor is stored as an integer. See for example:   http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html . Second: everything in R is an object. When you specify `col="red"` you are creating an (anonymous) `character` vector with length one and `red` as value and passing it as the `col` argument. You could also create an object before: `myCol<-"red"` and then specify `col=myCol`. This is basically what you did in your question.

Comment: But in my example, the character vector contains region values such as "East", "West", "North", "South". They are not color values like "red","blue" etc!. Did you mean to say that the values "east", "west" etc get converted to 1s and 0s. If so how do they become blue, red etc?

Comment: Again, `region` is not a `character` vector, but a `factor`. What you are passing are integer values. Your call is the same as `col=c(1,1,2,3,4)`. Did you read the link I provided in the previous comment?

Comment: The `Color Specification` section explains also that the color indices are taken by the default `palette`. Try `palette()` to get the default and read `?palette`.

Comment: Great! I understand it now :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are making sorts of graphs, look up http://coleoguy.blogspot.de/2016/06/symbols-and-colors-in-r-pch-argument.html

There is a tool for selecting colors: http://colorbrewer2.org/

Just remember, when you enter a series of colors in HEX, make sure you use caps: e.g.       col=c("#1B9E77","#D95F02","#7570B3","#666666")

Answer (score -1):

you have to put "with(SalesData,plot(year,sales,col=SalesData$region))" instead of
"with(SalesData,plot(year,sales,col=region))".